# Why Google Cloud TTL is not working (setup)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ttl

yetsterday I set a new rule in TTL in order to delete a firestore document. The status is "publishing..." from yesterday. Is it normal?
[image]

Comment: I think it's normal, showing the same for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I think it is normal. In my case the status showing serving whenever a new TTL policy is created, the status still showing serving even the document is deleted after its expiration date.

Data is typically deleted within 72 hours after its expiration date.TTL doesn't immediately invalidate data or hide it from queries when it becomes eligible for deletion.check [How does TTL work](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/ttl)

Note the following key behaviors of [TTL-driven deletion](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/ttl):

- Deletion through TTL is not an instantaneous process. Expired entities continue to appear in queries and lookup requests until the TTL process actually deletes them. TTL trades deletion timeliness for the benefit of reduced total cost of ownership for deletions.
- Applying a TTL policy on an existing kind results in a bulk deletion of all data that's expired according to the new TTL policy. Note that this bulk deletion is also not instantaneous.
- TTL does not necessarily delete entities in the same order as their expiration timestamps.

Comment: my problem is that TTL rule isn't published yet.

Comment: I think it’s normal.  For me also it’s showing like that.